# no media found error on usb drive

Tags: live-usb

I booted ubuntu 22.04 on usb dives and then tried to add some extra data into the flash and when I connected it back I could find it again.
here is what I tried
I did `lsblk`  and found the drive with 0 byte space.

I tried formating it with `mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb` and I got no media found error.

I also tried checking the filesystem for errors `fsck /dev/sdb` and `e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdb` but I still have no media found error even `fdisk` and `gdisk` are unable to read the drive I also tried `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb` and I had not cannot open /dev/sdb:
No medium found.

all the above commands were ran as root.

I am short of ideas and need help.

Comment: Not directly possible. Think of you usb device as "CD disk ro". There are some instructions in the wev on how to add a writable partiton on you USB.. But you will not get that out of the box

Comment: from what I understand you are trying to say it is impossible for the storage to just disappear or I don't get the point.

Comment: If you boot from "usb-drive" I assumed you had a live image on your drive. If not, forget my comment

Comment: What is the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sd?` Please [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1496847/edit) your question and add that information.

Comment: Please answer the previous comments by editing your original question. - And please answer also the following questions: 1. What is the full name of the iso file, from which you created the USB boot system? 2. What method/tool did you use to create a bootiable system in the USB drive? 3. What is the brand name and model of the computer? 4. What is the brand name and model of the graphics chip/card? - You will help us help you by telling us as much as possible about your Ubuntu system.

Comment: ```sudo fdisk -l  /dev/sdb``` gives cannot open /dev/sdb: No medium found.

Comment: Please try the following commands and edit your original question to show the output of the commands: 1. `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sd?` (yes, use a questionmark to look for also other drive letters, not only 'b'); 2. `lsblk -e7 -o model,name,size,fstype,label,mountpoints` -- Please try your USB drive via the other USB ports on the computer, and also try in some other computer. You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) and if you are lucky, find a solution.